# WPF ListBox with ComboBox, selected item if combobox is open

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a problem with my ListBox. Each ListBoxItem in the ListBox contains ComboBox. If the ComboBox in one ListBoxItem is open and then I click on another ListBoxItem, this item is not selected, only the ComboBox is closed. Or if the ComboBox in one ListBoxItem is open and then I click on another ComboBox, this ComboBox is not open.
Does anybody know what can be wrong with ComboBox?

Comment: This is the default behaviour of comboBox. Any click outside will be eaten up by comboBox popup to close itself.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. ComboBoxes Visual Studio have the same behaviour. But ComboBoxes for example in Word or Outlook have another behaviour.